# How can I map a binary network packet structure to Haskell standard data types (records)?

Tags: haskell, binary, network-programming, packet, bytestring

I want to implement a binary protocol (RFC3588, Diameter) with pure Haskell. I need to know is there any better way (Than e.g. Data.Binary...) to read/write data from/to ByteStrings. I like mapping a Haskell record to ByteString, as like what is usual in C# using StructLayout attribute (decorator).

Comment: Haskell does not give you any guarantees about memory layout so you can not simply cast a set of bytes as a struct - you must parse it using `binary` or something rather like it (`cereal`, `avro`, `attoparsec`, etc).

Comment: Since [AVP header layout depends on the flags](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6733#page-41) you can't really do it with `StructLayout` either.

Comment: You are right Cirdec, but I want to know the solution anyway for other uses.

Comment: Let me clarify my requirement more: In Python we can create a class with initialization constructor, and then use Struct package and * operator to map class fields to bytes format:

`class MyTest:
    def __init__(x:int, y:int):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y

m=MyTest(*struct.unpack('il'), b'\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haskell does not give you any guarantees about memory layout so you can not simply cast a set of bytes as a struct - you must parse it using binary or something rather like it (cereal, attoparsec, etc).

EDIT: For an example use of binary, consider:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

import Data.Binary
import GHC.Generics (Generic)

data Foo = Foo Int | Bar String deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read, Generic)

instance Binary Foo
```

Now you can `encode` and `decode` the `Foo` type to and from bytes.

Comment: I do not mean under the hood layout necessarily, I mean something simulating it, like in Python: struct package helps very much to convert bytestring (bytes in Python 3) to a standard Python class/tuple.

Comment: @Kamyar Binary instances provide exactly that though, so I still don't understand the problem.